# Android - Image button size

Tags: android, eclipse, image, button, imageview

My imagebutton code wont respond to "fill_parent" and "wrap_content".
Instead, it just shows the middle of the image (because it is a pretty big image).
I tried setting specific values for the image but it still didn't work! Can somebody help me?

My button.xml in the res/drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">\
<item android:state_pressed="true" 
android:drawable="@drawable/largishbutton" /> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true" 
android:drawable="@drawable/largerbutton2" /> <!-- focused -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/largerbutton" /> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

My main.xml in the res/layout folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:background="@android:color/white">
 <ImageButton
 android:src="@drawable/button"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  /> 
 </RelativeLayout>
```

I tried using a LinearLayout, but the app wouldnt run, and I tried replacing the imagebutton with an imageview, but then the button didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your image is bigger than your button, you will need to use something like [`android:scaleType`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType) or [`setMaxHeight()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setMaxHeight(int)) to have it resize to fit.

Also, I recommend that you have all images in your `<selector>` be the same size, at least until you get things working the way you wish.